# Can I define multiple nodes in nodeAffinity with a priority or a "weight"?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes pod and 4 nodes in my cluster. I would like to schedule that pod to `node-2` first if it's available and then `node-4`, `node-3` and last priority to `node-1`. Assuming that `node-x` is the built in `kubernetes.io/hostname` value, is there any way to possibly define a priority for these 4 nodes inside a `nodeAffinity`?

This is what I've tried:

```
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - node-2
            - node-4
            - node-3
            - node-1
```

However, the pod seems to always go to node-1.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
nodeAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
    - matchExpressions:
      - key: node-type
        operator: In
        values:
        # a common label applied to all nodes
        - node-label
  preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
  - weight: 100
    preference:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
        operator: In
        values:
        - node-2
  - weight: 50
    preference:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
        operator: In
        values:
        - node-4
  - weight: 20
    preference:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
        operator: In
        values:
        - node-3
.
.
and so on
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).